# Make AA wallet signature permanent

Tags: signature, polygon, account-abstraction

I have a 0xsequence wallet which implements AA, I am signing a EIP712 message using signTypedData and verifying with the SignatureChecker.sol using the function isValidSignatureNow. Everything seems okay but after some random time the signature becomes invalid, how can I make a AA wallet signature valid permanently?